# Programmatically set Registry Software Policy key for all Users

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

I need to set the following registry key for all standard user accounts. However, standard users don't have access to this location. How can I set this key programmatically, as an administer and have it available to all users when they login?

I've tried Registry Active Setup via calling **reg add**. However, this did not work because Active Setup runs with user permissions (I guess) which cannot set that key!

**Registry key:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Security\Trusted Protocols\All Applications\Custom:

Answer (score 1):

This key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Security\Trusted Protocols\All Applications\Custom:
```

Is Actually

```
HKEY_USERS\ Security ID (SID)\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Security\Trusted Protocols\All Applications\Custom:
```

You could query all users in HKEY_USERS and set this key for every one. The problem here would be that this key will not be set for new users.

Comment: HKEY_USERS will not have the necessary paths unless the profiles have been loaded. On a two user system (one admin and user user) you'll see both values if you run regedit as "admin". This causes two profiles to be loaded. However, the other profiles don't get put into HKEY_USERS, thus I can not write to them.

Comment: You could load the reg file associated to every user (C:\Users\<username>\ntuser.dat) and then modify the key.  Check out this article:
[link](http://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/modifying-the-registry-of-another-user/)